# Changing the Date print format, retaining its mode, class and type

Tags: r, date

I have a `Date` and I use `format` to change the printed format to e.g. `"%Y%m%d"`:

```
m <- as.Date("30-sep-15","%d-%b-%y")
l <- format(m, "%Y%m%d")
# [1] "20150930"
```

Now, the class of the formatted object is `character`:

```
class(l)
# "character"
```

The class and the mode is changed to `character`. Can we retain the `Date` class on this object, and still display this object in the following format: `20150930`?

Comment: Can't you just override the `print.Date` or `format.Date` method in `base`.?I mean I tried and couldn't do it :) - but I think you can somehow. Probably not a good thing to do either.

Comment: Why do we want to do this? Tell us more, so maybe there is a better approach to this problem.

Comment: I want to perform the operations of date, like generating sequence of subsequent 3 months by 
k=seq(m, by= "1 month", length.out= 4)
But I want k to be shown as (20150930,20151030,20151130), and not in the conventional date format

Comment: If you use my answer below, you can define a `seq.prettyDate` method that retains the "prettyDate" class, but please consider the comment by @zx8754.

Answer (score 5):

You can define your own S3 class with an associated `print` method:

```
m <- as.Date("30-sep-15","%d-%b-%y")
m

prettyDate <- function(x) {
  if (!inherits(x, "Date")) stop("Only objects of class 'Date' can be prettyDates.")
  class(x) <- c("prettyDate", class(x))
  x
}

m <- prettyDate(m)

print.prettyDate <- function(x, ...) {
  stopifnot(inherits(x, "Date"))
  print.default(format(x, "%Y%m%d"))
}

m
#[1] "20150930"
class(m)
#[1] "prettyDate" "Date"
```

If you also want your format printed in data.frames, you need to define a `format` method too.

`Date` methods will still be used for the object if there is no method for the additional class:

```
as.POSIXct(m)
#[1] "2015-09-30 02:00:00 CEST"
```

Comment: I tried your method, but after trying operations on this date

pp=seq(m,by= "1 month", length.out=3)

pp
[1] "2015-09-30" "2015-10-30" "2015-11-30"

Is there any way we can do such that the result from the operations on this prettydate data type is also in the same format?

Comment: See my comment above. However, most likely you should simply use the normal `Date` printing. Why do you insist on having your own format printed?

Comment: So I need to define a function for specifically printing the prettydate class in specified format? (I'm a bit new, so I'm not versed with some terms)